# New to Angular 2, attempting to load data into a table

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table

Let me start this off by saying I am very new to Angular2. So I am trying to load the list `EMPS` into my table. Here's my app.component.ts file which has the majority of my code so far

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Emp {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  office: string;
}

const EMPS: Emp[] = [
  { name: 'test1', email: 'test1@test.com', office: 'NY' },
  { name: 'test2', email: 'test2@test.com', office: 'LA' },
  { name: 'test3', email: 'test3@test.com', office: 'CHA' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div *ngFor="let d of data | async">
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>name: {{ d.name }}</h3>
            </td>
            <td> 
                <h3>email: {{ d.email }}</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h3>office: {{ d.office }}</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
  `,
  styles: [`

  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TestTable';
  emps = EMPS;
  data = this.emps;

}
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/0uCIB]

I am pretty lost at the moment and I have no clue what to do. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the use of the `async` pipe in your `*ngFor`. That should be used for iterating an Observable. You're using "static" content, not an Observable.

Comment: That's exactly it!

Comment: Glad to help! I will add if you're not familiar with Observables yet you should familiarize yourself with RxJS. Very useful and important in the world of Angular.